# django HTML ajax did not alert？

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I finally get the report successfully, but the ajax-alert did not show, just nothing shows in my website. why this happened? how to re-write hte code ? here is my code:
ajax:

```
function get_report(dataname){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/file_parse/",
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: true,
        data:JSON.stringify({
            'button':'button2',
            'data':dataname
        }),  //提交参数
        success:function (data) {
            if(data.status == 'success'){
                alert('OK')
            }
        }
    })
}

<td>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" name="{{item.sn}}" value="report" onclick="get_report(this.name)">
</td>
```

views:

```
if button_name == 'button2':
......
   report.save
   return HttpResponse("{'status':'success'}", content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: you returned the HttpResponse in the wrong format. The correct format is `return HttpResponse({'status':'success'}, content_type='application/json')`. No need of enclosing double quotes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return json format

```
return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

Comment: yeah，it worked! Thanks a lot! could you please tell me why this happened?

Comment: I don't know, I just use JsonResponse :))))

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return dict instead of string. Please check the modified **return** below.

```
return HttpResponse({'status':'success'}, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: could you please check this `console.log(data)` and post here what it is showing?

Comment: The JsonResponse worked, I do not know why...anyway, thanks

Comment: JsonResponse is same as dumping response to dict like this `return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status':'success'}), content_type='application/json')` returning json response to the ajax call.